# Event Delegation function to add comment field

Tags: jquery, function, events, comments, delegation

I want to create a function with jQuery with the Event Delegation so that i can leave a comment under a blogg post.
So i need a text field under each blog post and then be able to post a comment. Any help out there?

EDIT

Hi,

I just wrote a post, however I did not specify enough so I'll try to get into it a bit more :)

I have an API https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments
From this API i have to retrieve data (in this case they are made up blogg comments) when I click a button on my page. 
My code so far is:

```
    funtion renderBloggPosts () {
let $bloggPosts = $("#bloggPosts");
$bloggPosts.empty();
for (let product of posts) {
    let $product = $(`<div class="product">
        <div>${product.id}</div>
        <div>${product.title}</div>
        <div>${product.body}"></div>
        <div>${product.Likes} Likes</div>
        <div><button>Comment</button></div>
    </div>`);
    $product.find("button").on("click", () => {
            // showComments(product);
        });
        $product.appendTo($bloggPosts);
    }
}
```

The code above displays random blogg posts in the dom. Now i need to display random comments from the API above when I click the "comment" button...

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, please take the time to read the [tour] and [ask] pages.

Comment: Ive tried creating a function that simply creates a div to leave a comment but the problem is that the comment then appears on all blogg posts...

Comment: please, provide some code about the function which adds the comment and the dom structure of the blog post. We can't help you if we can't see what you've done